# Python: Event-Handler for background task complete

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

I have a `_global_variable = Big_Giant_Class()`. `Big_Giant_Class` takes a long time to run, but it also has constantly refreshing 'live-data' behind it, so I always want as new a instance of it as possible. Its not `IO-bound`, just a load of CPU computations.

Further, my program has a number of functions that reference that `global` instance of `Big_Giant_Class`.

I'm trying to figure out a way to create `Big_Giant_Class` in an endless loop (so I always have the latest-and-greatest!), but without it being blocking to all the other functions that reference `_global_variable`.

Conceptually, I kind of figure the code would look like:

```
import time
class Big_Giant_Class():
    def __init__(self, val, sleep_me = False):
        self.val = val
        if sleep_me:
            time.sleep(10)
    
    def print_val(self):
        print(self.val)    

async def run_loop():    
    while True:
        new_instance_value = await asyncio.run(Big_Giant_Class(val = 1)) # <-- takes a while
        # somehow assign new_instance_value to _global_variable when its done!        

def do_stuff_that_cant_be_blocked():
    global _global_variable    
    return _global_variable.print_val()

_global_variable = Big_Giant_Class(val = 0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(run_loop())  #<-- maybe I have to do this somewhere?
    
    for i in range(20):
        do_stuff_that_cant_be_blocked()
        time.sleep(1)        
        
Conceptual Out:
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
```

The kicker is, I have a number of functions [ie, `do_stuff_that_cant_be_blocked`] that can't be blocked.

I simply want them to use the last `_global_variable` value (which  gets periodically updated by some unblocking...thing?).  Thats why I figure I can't `await` the results, because that would block the other functions?

Is it possible to do something like that?  I've done very little `asyncio`, so apologies if this is basic. I'm open to any other packages that might be able to do this (although I dont think `Trio` works, because I have incompatible required packages that are used)

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Im a little confused on what you want. Are you wanting the program to have a normally running loop with another loop in the background that does tasks and when those tasks finish it calls the `event_handler` function?

Comment: Just one loop - the one thats constantly pumping out new instances of "my_class_instance".  But I need it to be non-blocking to the rest of my program, and to simply assign its result (when its 'done' running the calc) to _global_variable so that all my other functions can reference it

Comment: Yea that sounds like two loops. By loops I just mean flow of execution. One loop is background and updates a value and then a main loop that run the program code that uses the value. Is the background task that updates the value IO bound?

Comment: Hmm, I've probably made it sounds too complicated.  I'm going to rejig my question / 
 example.  1 min

Comment: One workaround for this kind of problem is the asyncio.loop.run_in_executor function: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor

Comment: I just editted the question - hopefully a bit more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have two cpu bound "loops" in your program. Python has a quirky threading model. So first off python CANNOT do two things at once, meaning calculations. Threading and async allow python to fake doing two things.

Threading allows you to "do" two things cause python switches between the threads and does work but doesnt run both at the same time

Async allows you to "do" two things if you can await the operation. While python awaits the operation it can jump and do something else. However awaiting a cpu bound operation will not allow it to jump and do other things.

The easiest solution is to use a thread though there will be some time where both loops are blocking cause work is being done on the other. But work will be split about 50/50 between threads.

```
from threading import Thread

_global_variable = some_initial_value


def update_global():
    global _global_variable

    while True:
        _global_variable = get_new_global_instance()
        call_some_event()


def main():
    background_thread = Thread(target=update_global, daemon=True)
    background_thread.start()

    while True:
        do_important_work()
```

The harder but truly multiprocessing version would be to use a `Process` instead of a `Thread` but would also need to use either shared state or a queue or something like that.
https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes

Comment: Thanks!  Using my (final) edit, I have use the example of waiting 10seconds and the print.  So in my mind, the CPU 'switches' to the print() calculation whenever its needed, then switches back to the long-running thing.  Is that what you mean by the 50/50 split between threads?  In my mind, it would be 99/1 split, because the other 'calling' functions are light calculation wise...

Comment: Python schedules threads in two ways. First is counting python operations for example after 100 ops it will switch to a different thread and so on. The second is sleeping. You can sleep for a period of time and once that time passes the thread is given focus. Sleeping will make the ratio different. Without sleeping its about 50/50. However cpus are so fast now that even sleeping for 10 ms could make it 99.99/0.01. Just do what works for you

Comment: If your question is answered just make sure to mark it as answered so it doesnt show up as unanswered.

Comment: Sorry - I was away from my computer.  I dont really follow you on the sleeping thing?  I would love if you could expand the answer maybe to explain that stuff?  To help others too who happen to find this.  In my mind, the rest of my 'program' is mostly idle time, waiting for user input.  During that idle time, I want that other thread pumping out instances of that big class.

Comment: Lastly - the "call_some_event()" in my mind was simply to set the new instance to _global_variable. But looking at your code, its not needed at all?

Comment: `time.sleep` blocks the thread for the specified amount of time so other threads can work. If your waiting on user input that is IO bound work and should allow the background thread to work while it waits for input. And no there is no reason why you have to have an event handler. You just said you needed it so i put it in my code.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks!  The event hander thing was me just being totally naive :)